# elastic search high level rest client v.7.5 java how to initialize

Tags: elasticsearch

from version 7.5 (latest as of now)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.5/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html

Can anyone tell me what is 9201 from the snippet?  Haven't been able to find any documentation on what that is.
Thanks!

```
client = new RestHighLevelClient(
    RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example to show connecting to multiple different ports. If you run 2 elasticsearch nodes on your local machine one of them will listen on 9200 and the other will listen on 9201.

You found more details about this [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rest-high-level-client-initialization-what-are-the-ports-needed/140033).